# I have a table composed of 5 images, how can i style this table so that it will scale proportionally on multiple browser sizes?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, css-tables

The image table looks fine except when you shrink the browser size and then the table expands past the window size. I don't need the table to be responsive (it is only 5 images), I need the table to scale with the browser size.

Here is the JSFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/gacujuvx/

this is how i styled one image in the stylesheet.

```
.comfyone    { 
  width:570px;
      height:214px;
      background:url(http://104.131.100.112/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/1stad1.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
   }
```

You can see the html table in the JSfiddle example I provided.

If somebody could provide an answer that works, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Use present measures

Comment: How do you expect the table to scale when you are forcing the width and height to absolute values?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the table to scale then you do need the table to be responsive. What do you think responsiveness is if not scaling depending on browser size?

```
.comfyone    { 
      width:20%;
   }
```

set your width and height in percentages so their size is based on the size of the screen